# Cocoa MQTT - Socket closed by remote peer

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm having major issues when I try connecting to my server with CocoaMQTT. I am running a Ubuntu server with the Mosquitto broker.

I have followed all the instructions given but I still can't find a solution.

I have used the standard Cocoa connection function.

```
private func createMQTTConnection() {
    let clientID = "CocoaMQTT-" + String(ProcessInfo().processIdentifier)
    mqtt = CocoaMQTT(clientID: clientID, host: "xxx.xx.xx.x", port: 1883)
    mqtt!.username = "root"
    mqtt!.password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    //mqtt.willMessage = CocoaMQTTWill(topic: "pi/pir", message: "dieout")
    mqtt!.keepAlive = 60
    mqtt!.delegate = self
    mqtt!.allowUntrustCACertificate = true
    mqtt!.connect()
```

This code is then called in the viewDidLoad

```
verride func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    //establishes a connection 
    createMQTTConnection()
     // creates a message 
     mqtt!.publish("pi/pir", withString: "Iphone Connected")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

I have all the other standard  cocoaMQTT items

```
extension MQTT: CocoaMQTTDelegate {

func mqttDidPing(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT) {
    print("mqttDidPing")
}

func mqttDidReceivePong(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT) {
    print("mqttDidReceivePong")

}

func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didPublishAck id: UInt16) {
    print("didPublishAck : \(id)")
}

func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didPublishComplete id: UInt16) {
    print("didPublishComplete: \(id)")
}

func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didSubscribeTopic topic: String) {
    print("didSubscribeTopic: \(topic)")
}

func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didUnsubscribeTopic topic: String) {
    print("didUnsubscribeTopic: \(topic)")
}

func mqttDidDisconnect(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, withError err: Error?) {
    print("mqttDidDisconnect: \(err?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
}

func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didConnectAck ack: CocoaMQTTConnAck) {
    print("didConnectAck: \(ack)")
}

func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didPublishMessage message: CocoaMQTTMessage, id: UInt16) {
    print("didPublishMessage: \(message) and \(id)")
}

func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didReceiveMessage message: CocoaMQTTMessage, id: UInt16) {
    print("didReceiveMessage: \(message) and \(id)")
}

func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didReceive trust: SecTrust, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    print("didReceive trust")
}

}
```

I then receive the following error;

didPublishMessage:  and 2
mqttDidDisconnect: Socket closed by remote peer

Any help would be greatly appreciated. **Thanks**

Comment: Edit the question to include the logs from the broker

Comment: There are no logs from the broker due to it not connecting. when I publish the message it won't go through to the broker because a connection isn't established. The broker works as I am able to publish messages from my android app I've created. is there anything else I can post that will help with diagnosis?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `connect` is an asynchronous call and you likely aren't connected at the time you're calling publish. Try moving your `publish` into the `didConnect` delegate method.

```
func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didConnect host: String, port: Int) {
    print("mqtt did connect to \(host):\(port)")
    mqtt.publish("pi/pir", withString: "Iphone Connected")
}
```

log:

```
mqtt did connect to 192.168.1.104:1883 
didPublishMessage: <CocoaMQTT.CocoaMQTTMessage: 0x1c0674100> and 2
```